Effect of number of component and How to plot DOS
I'm studying DOS these days.
I followed some examples from YouTube and other papers,
but I have a question:
Does the number of components affect the DOS?
At first, I thought so. But I changed my mind a little.
It's because VASP uses a periodic system. A unit cell is the smallest unit that repeats. So, if it has the same structure and the same atoms, the number of components doesn't affect the DOS.
It doesn't make sense if the DOS results of 10 atoms and 100 atoms are different.

Have you compared dos(density of states) by dividing the unit-cell included in the supercell? Plus, I could not understand second question. Please give more informations.

Thanks for answering.
IN vasp manual, DOS units is states/(number of atom * ev). You means that divide it by unit cell volume?
And second question is, total DOS is different with sum of orbitals. in my case, Si, total DOS is different with sum of s and d orbitals. so i wonder that i need to do something else.

In my first question, the answer I found is related to band folding:
Why is the band structure of a supercell more dense than for simple cell?
